# Replicate SELinux issue on CentOS VM

Tags: ssh, centos7, selinux

I have a CentOS 7.6 virtual machine on my workplace's network that I have access to via SSH, and only SSH. I recently tried to install OKD on it and ran into a problem through which, after setting SELinux to "enforcing" (this bit is necessary for OKD), I couldn't connect anymore to the machine. The machine had to be redeployed by IT.

Now I am trying to replicate the problem in a Windows Hyper-V virtual machine running CentOS 7.6, in order to be able to redeploy it on my own instead of annoying IT, and also having direct access in case I have to use it and can't connect through SSH.

The thing is, when trying to replicate the error, it didn't occur, and everything worked just fine. So now I am coming here to look for help, **can anyone tell me what could have caused this error so I can replicate it?**

The error message whenever I tried to connect with a root user (the machine had only root users) to the locked machine was:

```
/bin/bash permission denied
```

PS: Someone told me in a recent question that it may be an issue with relabeling, and to use `touch /.autorelabel` to relabel the file system on reboot, but I didn't need to do it on my VM, so I will not risk using an incorrect solution for the network machine and get locked out again.

Comment: In effect, asking to 'replicate the issue' when it didn't occur out of the box is the equivalent of diagnosing it precisely. Unless you've got audit logs of the actual host system that was deployed its not likely anyone can actually replicate the problem.

Comment: The thing is that, other than SELinux, nothing really changed, so I don't even know which logs to post. If you know of anything that could help diagnose it, I'll be eager to post it.
I know the question is quite broad, but I am quite a newbie with linux, and even more with CentOS, so it is extremely hard for me to find a solution.

Comment: We'd need the output of `ausearch -m avc` You can specify a time you performed the attempted work but you didn't specify a date or time in the question you tried it.